# ISV 15% revenue share details

Tags: appexchange

I've searched google and stackexchange and the closest thing to answering my question is here: [Integrating our 3rd party application with Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14784/integrating-our-3rd-party-application-with-salesforce/14805#14805)

We have a SaaS app that can run completely independent of Salesforce on our own website.  For customers of ours that use Salesforce, we would like to embed a widget into the Contact/Lead/Account pages.  This widget will communicate back to our servers to populate it's content. We have created these widgets and apex classes inside our developer org and they work fine.

Here is roughly how we plan to charge:
For our app without salesforce: $250/month + $3/user/month
For salesforce integration: $150/month + $2/user/month

I have no problem paying Salesforce 15% of the salesforce integration side (We would love the extra exposure on AppExchange).  How do we account for it and report to Salesforce on it?  If for some of my customers, I want to give the Salesforce integration for free as a bonus, how do we account for that?

I'm just in the processing of signing up as an ISV partner so maybe these details are discussed then?  I saw a reference to a Channel Order App  but am not sure how it fits in. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/coa_intro.htm

Comment: Each Installation via App Exchange will pop up in the License Management App. Here you manage access to you app, e.g. extend trial licenses. This is the technical side. The Channel Order App which is currently reworked is the place we're u officially inform Salesforce of new contracts. It is not directly related to the licences u manage and this part will be set up with your AE and define prices/products etc. U will be billed by things entered in Order App.

Comment: The Salesforce AE (Account Executive) would help on this. Also please go through the License Management and Channel Order app to manage license etc. These are the place from where revenue sharing decision and calculation happen.